# Solving Inequalities based on variable value symolic math tool box MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am new to Symbolic math tool box. I am trying to solve the symbolic expressions and I need one peculier method. I dont know whether it is possible or not

I have an equation like below

```
z = x + a/b*log(1 + a/c) ---> if a/c > 0.0002

  = x+ log(a/c+b)----> if a/c <= 0.0002
```

is there any way to solve the 'z' based on the given condition? I am not allowed to use If statements or switch cases

something like s

```
solve(z, a/c=0.1)
```

reading a/c value and solving z

Thank you in advance

Comment: A and c are constants right? Solve both, and get expresions for both. You can not know which of the solutions to use until someone gives you `a` and `c`. If someone does give you those variables, then you know which of the 2 solutions is the one you want

Comment: A and c are varibales but before start of the code these two variables will get their values(constant). hence these two are constants. my requirement is when these values are given I have to solve correct Z. and should ignore other

Comment: so use a `if` condition?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [piecewise](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html).

Comment: It works for my requirement. Thanks @jodag